# bash script to create and print string into files from list

Tags: bash

I'm on opensus 11.3 and I am looking for a bash script to do the following:

1. Create directories and rename them from a `.txt` list, each new name is a new line on that .txt
2. Copy `file.php` from to each new directory, and rename all `file.php` files in those directories to a specific name.
3. Print a `"/< php ?  >/"` string into the first line in each of those files.

I assume the best and fastest to accomplish this will be in bash, if you have another idea I will be happy to listen.

Comment: See my answer. You didn't say to what name the dirs should be renamed & to what name should be file.php renamed. Provide this information and I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: The folder names should taken by order from list.txt and the file indide is a specific name "filename.php". 
I tried What you wrote it does not create the folders.

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer. What about this dir renaming?

Comment: Great it does that, Thanks pajton, you saved me long time here. :)

Comment: let me ask you, what if the string that it prints inside will be the a php code that will like <php $city= "the folder name from the list" ?> ? Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: This works nice but if there is a space in the name from names.txt it doesn’t take the full name it, Also I just noticed, even while creating the folders if the names.txt name has a space it crate folders for each word.

Comment: You're right. I had to check that in docs to be able to cope with this one:)

Comment: Thanks for your time, this code still does not create the folders with same name from names.txt if it has spaces, and also gives error for copying the file into the folder. (cp: target `Springs/filename.php' is not a directory)

Comment: This time I forgot to quote, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**: This is the version modified according to OP's last comment:

```
#/bin/bash

while read name; do
    # prepare file to copy into new dirs
    echo "\<php \$city= \"$name\" ?\>" > tempfile
    cat file.php >> tempfile

    # create dir & copy modified file.php into it
    mkdir -p "$name"
    cp tempfile "$name"/filename.php
done < names.txt
```

Comment: use `mkdir -p`, to avoid errors when crating subdirectories directly.